# finding subsets of a Array in java using backtracking/recursion

Tags: java, subset, backtracking

i am trying to find all subsets of a ArrayList using backtracking/recursion and below are my main meathod and method to findSubsets

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] s = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> result= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
        ArrayList<Character> t= new ArrayList<Character>();
        findSubsets(s,t,0,result);
    }
    static void findSubsets(char[] s,ArrayList<Character> t,int i,ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> result) {
        if(i >= s.length) {
            if(t.size()>0) {
                result.add(t);
                printArrayListOfArrayList(result);
            }
            return;
        }
        findSubsets(s,t,i+1,result);
        ArrayList<Character> tmp1 = new ArrayList<>(t);  
        tmp1.add(s[i]); 
        findSubsets(s,tmp1,i+1,result);
    }
```

i tried earlier with

```
        findSubsets(s,t,i+1,result);
        t.add(s[i]); 
        findSubsets(s,tmp1,i+1,result);
```

it didnt worked, and below code works perfectly

```
        findSubsets(s,t,i+1,result);
        ArrayList<Character> tmp1 = new ArrayList<>(t);  
        tmp1.add(s[i]); 
        findSubsets(s,tmp1,i+1,result);
```

why t.add(s[i]) and then calling recursion function wont find subsets?
where as new List with same data added tmp1.add(s[i]) will find subsets?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you tried with:

```
        findSubsets(s,t,i+1,result);
        ArrayList<Character> tmp1 = new ArrayList<>(t); 
        t.add(s[i]); 
        findSubsets(s,tmp1,i+1,result);
```

and not :

```
        findSubsets(s,t,i+1,result);
        t.add(s[i]); 
        findSubsets(s,tmp1,i+1,result);
```

In this case, t is non-zero, but when you call the function again recursively, `findSubsets(s,tmp1,i+1,result)`, for the prototype, `findSubsets(char[] s,ArrayList<Character> t,int i,ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> result)`, `t` becomes null again, thus the condition `if(t.size()>0)` fails. So `result` is not updated.